# How to sync maven artifact from jcenter to maven central?

Tags: bintray, jcenter, maven-central

I have an artifact (jar) that is deployed to bintray and is available on jcenter.   I would also like this artifact to be available on maven central.
The instructions available from bintray (located here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Syncing+with+Third-Party+Platforms) tell me to click the "Maven Central" tab within the "version" page for a version of my artifact within the bintray UI.  Unfortunately, there is no "Maven Central" tab on that page.  Any advice on how to get this artifact synced from bintray/jcenter to maven central?
Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I was able to get my artifact synced from jcenter to maven central by using the bintray "maven_central_sync" REST API.   However, I would still like to know how to do this from the bintray UI if possible though.

Answer (score 10):

Currently, there is no option to sync to Maven Central when using the new UI look. You will first need to switch to the "old look" of Bintray. This can be done by selecting the "Go to Old Look" option. (Screenshot #1) Then, after switching to the old look, select the "Maven Central" option (Screenshot #2).

I hope this helps.

[image: #1]

[image]

Comment: Aha!  Thanks for that info.  It wasn't obvious from the various docs I was looking in.  On the other hand, the lack of support in the new-look UI forced me to find a way to automate this maven-central sync step as part of my travis build (using the bintray REST API).

Answer (score 2):

The **most important part** to sync with Maven central is surprisingly omitted from every. single. article there exists. The credentials **are not** the Sonatype JIRA credentials, which are also the same for [Nexus Repository Manager](https://oss.sonatype.org/#welcome). After logging into Nexus Repository Manager, click on 'Profile' on the top right, and then from the drop down, choose 'User Token'. Click button 'Access New Token' to generate the credentials to be used by Bintray to sync with Maven Central.